# Flexslider not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, flexslider

I'm trying to get Flexslider to work on the following page — http://www.mattpealing.co.uk/_concept/fddds/dev/ — but I can't get it to animate properly for the life of me.

It seems to be loading all the js and css scripts properly, and I can see the inline styles have been applied to the elements in the DOM.

It's just getting the thing to actually move is the problem I'm having. Here is my script:

```
$('#feed-testimonials-home .feed').flexslider({
    animation: 'slideLeft',
    slideshow: 0,
    slideshowSpeed: 150,
    animationSpeed: 500,
    keyboard: 0
});
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end — `slideshow: 1`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Evgeniy That's an answer. It really shouldn't be edited into the question. One could argue that it was a typo an the question should be deleted altogether.